# Can't remove digest field from SQLite database in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I added a column to an SQLite table as follows

```
add_column :administrators, :pin, :digest
```

Now I want to remove it. I used

```
remove_column :administrators, :pin, :digest
```

That gives me this error

```
undefined method `to_sym' for nil:NilClass
```

Why doesn't it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe that `:digest` is a valid storage type for SQLite.  This is the same problem you get when you use a mis-spelled or otherwise incorrect storage type, e. g.

```
add_column :administrators, :sign_in_count, :integr
```

Because `:integr` is misspelled, subsequent migrations produce the `to_sym` error

Best recommendation is to do `rake db:rollback` until you reach the point where you haven't yet created the `pin` column, then change the column to a supported type such as `:string`

```
add_column :administrators, :pin, :string
```

and you can `rake db:migrate` to go forward again.

You should also do the same on the remove for consistency...

```
remove_column :administrators, :pin, :string
```

(Of course, if you don't want the column, you could just remove the `add_column` and `remove_column` once you roll back far enough.)

This assumes you're working alone... if you're working on shared development or with a deployed project you'll need to coordinate this with others working on the project, and note that any tables and fields that were created between the `add_column` migration and the final migration would be re-initialized and so you may lose some data in your development (and other) environments.  You'll also need to reset your test schema at the end of this with

`rake db:test:prepare`